# Is overflow defined for VHDL numeric_std signed/unsigned

Tags: standards, vhdl, integer-overflow

If I have an `unsigned(MAX downto 0)` containing the value `2**MAX - 1`, do the VHDL (87|93|200X) standards define what happens when I increment it by one? (Or, similarly, when I decrement it by one from zero?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:**

There is no overflow handling, the overflow carry is simply lost. Thus the result is simply the integer result of your operation *modulo 2^MAX*.

**Longer answer:**

The `numeric_std` package is a standard package but it is not is the Core the VHDL standards (87,93,200X).
For reference : [numeric_std.vhd](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/packages/numeric_std.vhd)

The `+` operator in the end calls the `ADD_UNSIGNED (L, R : unsigned; C : std_logic)` function (with `C = '0'`). Note that any integer/natural operand is first converted into an `unsigned`.

The function's definition is:

```
function ADD_UNSIGNED (L, R : unsigned; C : std_logic) return unsigned is
    constant L_left : integer   := L'length-1;
    alias XL        : unsigned(L_left downto 0) is L;
    alias XR        : unsigned(L_left downto 0) is R;
    variable RESULT : unsigned(L_left downto 0);
    variable CBIT   : std_logic := C;
begin
    for i in 0 to L_left loop
        RESULT(i) := CBIT xor XL(i) xor XR(i);
        CBIT      := (CBIT and XL(i)) or (CBIT and XR(i)) or (XL(i) and XR(i));
    end loop;
    return RESULT;
end ADD_UNSIGNED;
```

As you can see an "overflow" occurs if `CBIT='1'` (carry bit) for `i = L_left`. The result bit `RESULT(i)` is calculated normally and the last carry bot value is ignored.

Comment: Exactly the sort of reference I wanted, thanks :) (Please ignore my previous comment about the carry bit, I misread the function!)

Comment: This answer is also erroneous assuming role over with a length of MAX + 1.  It's a problem with using the name MAX. For somename declared as an unsigned with a subtype indication (index range) of 31 downto 0 and a length of 32 (somename'length) the Maximum value with a right index of 0 is 2**32 -1.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the problem with wanting an `unsigned` to overflow/underflow as in C or in Verilog and here is what I came up with (`result` and `delta` are `unsigned`):

```
result <= unsigned(std_logic_vector(resize(('1' & result) - delta, result'length))); -- proper underflow
result <= unsigned(std_logic_vector(resize(('0' & result) + delta, result'length))); -- proper overflow
```

For overflow `'0' & result` makes an `unsigned` which is 1 bit larger to be able to correctly accommodate the value of the addition. The MSB is then removed by the `resize` command which yields the correct overflow value. Same for underflow.

Comment: The default VHDL unsigned behaviour is to perform modulo-arithmetic and wrap around just like what we see in C/C++. So if result and delta are of type unsigned(7 downto 0), and their values are 10 and 20 respectively, you get 246 for (result - delta) which is -10%(2**8).

Answer (score 1):

For a value of MAX equal to 7 adding 1 to 2**7 - 1 (127) will result in the value 2**7 (128).

The maximum unsigned value is determined by the length of an unsigned array type:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture faa of foo is
    constant  MAX: natural := 7;
    signal somename:  unsigned (MAX downto 0) := (others => '1');
begin
UNLABELED:
    process
    begin
        report "somename'length = " & integer'image(somename'length);
        report "somename maximum value = " &integer'image(to_integer(somename));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The aggregate `(others => '1')` represents a '1' in each element of `somename` which is an unsigned array type and represents the maximum binary value possible.

This gives:

> foo.vhdl:15:9:@0ms:(report note): somename'length = 8
>   foo.vhdl:16:9:@0ms:(report note): somename maximum value = 255

The length is 8 and the numerical value range representable by the unsigned array type is from 0 to 2**8 - 1 (255), the maximum possible value is greater than 2**7 (128) and there is no overflow.

This was noticed in a newer question [VHDL modulo 2^32 addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609749/vhdl-modulo-232-addition). In the context of your accepted answer it assumes you meant length instead of the leftmost value.

The decrement from zero case does result in a value of 2**8 - 1 (255) (MAX = 7).  An underflow or an overflow depending on your math religion.

Hat tip to Jonathan Drolet for pointing this out in the linked newer question.