# VHDL modulo 2^32 addition

Tags: overflow, vhdl, sha

I am working on a VHDL implementation of the [SHA-256](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf) hash function.
I have some 32-bit `unsigned` signals defined as such:

```
SIGNAL a, b : UNSIGNED (31 downto 0);
```

Within the specifications of the SHA-256 algorithm, it says addition must be performed modulo 2^32 in order to retain the 32-bit size in case of an overflow.    Now, according to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769754/is-overflow-defined-for-vhdl-numeric-std-signed-unsigned) question, it sounds like overflow is already handled with modular addition in VHDL:

> There is no overflow handling, the overflow carry is simply lost. Thus the result is simply the integer result of your operation modulo 2^MAX.

I have 2 questions:

1. In my case, `MAX = 31` so does that mean that any addition operation I perform on `a` and `b` will be modded with 2^31?
2. I need to perform addition modulo 2^**32** which obviously doesn't make sense since I am working with 32-bit numbers and 2^32 is one bit too large.  So is it somehow implied that I should actually be modding with 2^**31**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are fine with `unsigned(31 downto 0)`. The `2^MAX` in the post you reference is an error and should read `2^length`. The length of `31 downto 0` is 32.

Think about it, `31 downto 0` can represent numbers from 0 to 2^32-1, it wouldn't make much sense if any addition of that range would be modulo 2^31 if you can represent larger numbers!

I'm not sure I understand your second question, but addition modulo 2^32 yields results in the range of 0 to 2^32-1. 2^32 is illegal, thus it's quite fine that you can't represent it with your unsigned.

Comment: So VHDL would indeed take care of applying mod 2^32 to the result of the addition of the 32-bit unsigned, and I shouldn't have to explicitly perform it?

Comment: Yes, default behaviour for unsigned addition/substraction in VHDL is modulo. Non-modulo addition or overflow detection is actually harder, not much though.

Comment: Computer's integer arithmetic works on *residue class rings*. The computer does not calculate mod 2^32. It's just the result by discarding all bits above bit 31. Or in other words because 32 is a power of 2 -> mod 2^32  equals the lower 32 bits from bit 0 to 31 :).